# Feeds not getting updated in ticker in chat room

Tags: support, bug, chat, feed

We have added feeds in ticker in our chat room, as we add feeds after removing, it gets displayed. but after dismiss of ticker, we are not getting back when feeds get updated.

Comment: Sounds by design to me. Can you give me a link to the chatroom and I'll go and investigate?